# real-time jwt token expiration management

Tags: angular, rxjs, jwt

I manage the expiration of the JWT token inside the interceptor.
The problem I would like is to be done what I do, when the token expires and not when the user requests an API request.

Because currently, I check that the token has expired every time a JWT request is intercepted, so during inactivity the user will only be redirected if he makes a new api call.
Is there a way to check for token expiration throughout the execution process, even when the page is idle?

Actually i do:

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<T>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    var token = this.sessionService.getToken();

    if (token != null && this.sessionService.isTokenExpired()) {
      this.toastrService.warning(
        'You will be redirected to the login page',
        'Session Expired',
        {
          timeOut: 10000,
        }
      );
      localStorage.clear();
      sessionStorage.clear();
      window.location.href = '/login';
    } else {
      if (this.authFacade) {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authFacade.accessToken}`,
          },
        });
      }
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a token checking periodically excluding the login page in some auth service with `interval` operator

```
// every 30 seconds
interval(300000).pipe(tap(()=>{
     this.toastrService.warning(
        'You will be redirected to the login page',
        'Session Expired',
        {
          timeOut: 10000,
        }
      );
      localStorage.clear();
      sessionStorage.clear();
      window.location.href = '/login';

}))
```

Comment: and where i can put this?

Comment: In a share service provide in root (maybe call it auth.service) and run it in the app container component. That way, you can always stop/start this background task from inner component as needed.